# How to add "order desc" in Paypal Europe prestashop module?

Tags: php, paypal, prestashop-1.6

I have paypal-europe module configured with my prestashop.
The problem is that in every payment the cart description says "cart"...

I cant filter my paments couse i dont know where are they from...

is there any possibility to add "cart description" in checkout?

On PayPal info there is only "Koszyk" text that means "Cart" ... i wish to have order name or shop name if possible...

Here is paypal payment info screenshot:
[image]

Comment: this is not a well-explained issue... show some code that you have tried, no body is going to code the whole thing for you

Comment: im not asking for coding for me... its free official module to prestashop and im just asking that anybody know the reason why there is no order number send to paypal from prestashop.